# trying to customise annotation pin

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkpinannotationview

I am trying to add a callout accessory to some existing code.
Here is my annotation main code:

```
OTNVenueAnnotation *annotation = [[OTNVenueAnnotation alloc] init];
annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.latitude, location.longitude);
annotation.title = [[venue objectForKey:@"name"] uppercaseString];
annotation.venue = venue;

MKPinAnnotationView* customPinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                      initWithAnnotation:annotation];

UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        [rightButton addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(showDetails:)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        customPinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;   

[self.mapView addAnnotation: annotation];
```

The build error is:
 No visible @interface for 'MKPinAnnotationView' declares the selector 'initWithAnnotation:'

Answer (score 0):

The method name is `initWithAnnotation:reuseIdentifier:`

You need to provide your annotation view with an NSString as the reuse identifier argument at initialization.

```
MKPinAnnotationView *customPinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                                     reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"];
```